# How to create ArgumentMatchers.any(type: Class<T>) for testing in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, mockito-kotlin

I'm trying to unit test a class that uses the following service:

```
parserService.parseJsonStringToModel(json: String, adapterClass: Class<T>): T?
```

My first approach was to use `ArgumentMatchers` to implement unit testing as follows:

```
Mockito.`when`(parserService.parseJsonStringToModel(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any<CreateAccountRequest>().javaClass)).thenReturn(null)
```

Since `ArgumentMatchers.any()` returns `null` in Kotlin, that produces `NullPointerException` for non nullable types. So I give a try to [Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) library to avoid this problem. The approach looks like following:

```
whenever(parserService.parseJsonStringToModel(any(), any<CreateAccountRequest>().javaClass)).thenReturn(null)
```

Used library solves the problem for first argument but still produces `NullPointerException` for passed second argument.

So, how can I create an `ArgumentMatchers` for `Class<T>` type arguments?

Comment: Using `any<Class<CreateAccountRequest>>()` for the second parameter doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes Sir, it worked!! Thank you @tynn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply create a matcher directly for `Class<CreateAccountRequest>`:

```
whenever(
    parserService.parseJsonStringToModel(
        any(),
        any<Class<CreateAccountRequest>>()
    )
).thenReturn(null)
```